# Why does right click not work on ChromeBook?

Tags: android, qt, touchscreen, chromebook

I try to code an application with C++/Qt which runs on Windows, Mac, Chrome OS ...

On my ChromeBook, the Right Click (to show the default context menus on lineEdits (copy/paste...) or to show custom context menus) does have the same comportment than the Left Click, so I have not the capacity to show any context menu.
I've tried 3 ways for the Right Click :

- The 2 taps on the trackpad
- The "Alt" + Click on the trackpad combo
- The Mouse connected via USB, right click

Each way produce a Left Click on my application, where, on other "official" apps (Google Chrome explorer for example), the Right Click is correct.

Asus C433T ChromeBook Chrome OS version 93.0
Qt 5.15.2 Qt Creator 5.0.2 build for compileSdkVersion 29 - archi x86 - JDK 14.0.1 - NDK 21.3

Note : my ChromeBook has a touchscreen

How to achieve the correct right click behaviour in my application?

Comment: When not explicitly stated, obvious means assuming, and assuming is usually to be avoided. "How to solve this": I would file a bug report if I were you. https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa